# Windows 10 randomly logs user out while they are using it

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, power-management, dell-latitude

This will be quite a long one so lets start here:

2x users are having the same exact issue with both Dell 5590's on windows 10. I pick one of them to be a Guinea Pig and test some solutions.

Both users state that their Dell 5590 laptop is logging them out randomly around 3x times a day.
We troubleshoot with the following:

- Changing Power Plan to not allow sleep/hibernation
- Updating all Drivers (including graphics driver) and bios to latest version
- Changing lid detector to do nothing via Group Policy
  *Side note after changing lid to have no action icons started getting moved around on the
  desktop upon being locked out
- Updating Windows to the latest version
- Uninstalling Cisco Orbital
- Temporarily suspending Cisco AMP
- Swapping out users power adapter and dock to a WD19

After doing all of this the user stated that the issue was still occurring. By this time we had found that the user would normally get locked out around 9 or 10 in the morning 1ish in the afternoon and then around 3-4 in the afternoon.

We then swapped the user to a completely newly imaged Dell 5511. This new PC had only the base image and no special programs installed. The only thing that has been consistent across everything would be her user account. I have not check dynamic locking as I have seen it around in other threads. Is there an user setting in Active Directory that might be causing this? I have pretty much hit a wall and don't want to get lost in dell support limbo. Thanks!

Comment: Have you formatted the devices and reimagined using your standard image?

Comment: Yes, the new 5511 that was given to the user was formatted and imaged with our standard used for all other PC's. The only files that were moved between the new and old were those located on the desktop and documents folder. They only consisted of Microsoft documents. Word, Excel ect...

Comment: Does this happen when Windows is booted into a minimal boot configuration.  Are they being logged out or is the device being locked due to perhaps an extremely short amount of time?  How does the logging out of the user result in the account being locked?